# Unable to write the CSV file

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, csv

I want to store only crawled urls in an array using JavaScript. here is my code:

```
var Crawler = require("js-crawler");
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var page= require('pa11y');

new Crawler().configure({depth: 2})
  .crawl("http://www.nature.com/", function onSuccess(page) {
    console.log('crawl:'+page.url);
  }, null, function onAllFinished(crawledUrls) {
    console.log('All crawling finished');
    console.log('crawl:' +crawledUrls);


var crawled = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < crawledUrls.length; i++)
           {
            crawled.push({

              'url': crawledUrls[i]

            });
          }

    storeCSV(crawled);
console.log(crawled);

function storeCSV(storeJSArray) {

  fs.writeFile('C:/Users/Desktop/dashboard-master/data/crawl.csv', storeJSArray, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File saved!');
  });
}
  });
```

The problem is that I'm getting output as follows:

```
[object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

I want the output as

```
crawl:http://www.nature.com/
All crawling finished
crawl:http://www.nature.com/

C:\Users\Desktop\dashboard-master\config>node crawler.js
crawl:http://www.nature.com/
crawl:http://authorservices.springernature.com/scientific-editing/?utm_source=na
tureAuthors&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=natureAuthors
crawl:http://authorservices.springernature.com/language-editing/?utm_source=natu
reAuthors&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=natureAuthors
crawl:http://www.nature.com/search?article_type=research-highlights&amp;order=da
te_desc
All crawling finished
crawl:http://www.nature.com/,http://authorservices.springernature.com/scientific
-editing/?utm_source=natureAuthors&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=natu
reAuthors,http://authorservices.springernature.com/language-editing/?utm_source=
natureAuthors&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=natureAuthors,http://www.
nature.com/search?article_type=research-highlights&amp;order=date_desc
```

Am i missing out anything. Any advise on this would be helpful.

Comment: shouldn't that be `(new Crawler()).configure`?

Answer (score 0):

You have included json2csv, but you are not using it. You are passing the crawled array containing objects directly to fs.WriteFile it calls .toString() and the result is [object Object] string.

Include this snippet

```
var csv = json2csv({ data: crawled, fields: ['url'] });
storeCSV(csv);
```